# How to implement datatable with child rows in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

Currently im using the basic(zero configuration) datatable. Below are the codes that im currently using

**Views**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($my_furniture_info as $fur)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $fur->name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $my_furniture_info = Furniture::all();

    return view('furniture.admin',compact('my_furniture_info'));
}
```

Now i wanted to make datatable that have child rows just like this [datatable documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). The problem is that i dont know how to get my furniture data ($my_furniture_info) to show into the child row. I will be appreciated if we could use the chat function in stackoverflow.

**In the documentation**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?",
```

Comment: anyone can guide me through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this - https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "data/arrays.txt"
} );
} );
```

and arrays.txt would be like -

```
[
"Tiger Nixon",
"System Architect",
"Edinburgh",
"5421",
"2011/04/25",
"$3,120"
]
```

I have copied from the same page...

Comment: but i would like to get the data from the database, not from a text files

Comment: So use php to get data from database and create such text files or then use ajax.

Comment: could you show me a snippets of the codes? as you can see, i included a snippets of my codes that i retrieve data from database in controller